how to get value from polars DataFrame
from sum(), I need value of sum().I could get it by this, but more better way?
1: make dataframe column to series,
2: change it to list,
3: get value from list
a = df["columns name"].to_list()[i]   #i = list vaue no
print(a)                              # value

more simple way to get value of DataFrame sum() results.

How about df["column name"].sum()?

Thanks. It gets value of one element series. From polars Doc, polars.Series.sum Series.sum() → int | float[source] Reduce this Series to the sum value.

this is from first sum()==>    df.sum()["A"].sum()
